# Show there's some $k$ and scalars that give zero for linear combination of $T$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, solution-verification, linear-transformations, proof-explanation

Let $V$ be a finitely generated vector space and $T ∈ L(V )$. Show that there is some $k ≥ 0$ and scalars $a_0, a_1, · · · , a_k$ not all zero such that $a_0I + a_1T + a_2T^2 + · · · + a_kT^k = Z$, where $Z$ is the zero function, so that $Z(x) = 0$ for all $x ∈ V$.

Hi, I'm having a tough time with this question.

Here's what I think so far:

$T$ maps from $V$ to $V$, and since it's finitely generated, have $dim(V) = n$, some $n$. So, the dimension of $T∈L(V)$ is $n^2$.

Now, $(a_0I + a_1T + a_2T^2 + · · · + a_kT^k)(x) = Z(x)$, (where $T^2$ is composition $T$ of $T$)

And since T is linear, have $a_0I(x) + a_1T(x) + a_2T^2(x) + · · · + a_kT^k(x) = Z(x)= 0$

So $a_0(x) + a_1T(x) + a_2T^2(x) + · · · + a_kT^k(x)= 0$
Now we know that not all $a_i$'s are zero, and we need to find some $k$ where the set {$I, T, T^2,...,T^k$} is linearily dependent.

Now since $dim T∈L(V) = n^2$, have that the basis of the vector space will have size $n^2$. So, any $k>n^2$ will make {$I, T, T^2,...,T^k$} linearly dependent.

I need to show why $k>n^2$ or explain this reasoning.

Okay I'm not sure about anything I wrote so far, and I'm lost at this point.

Thanks for all the help!!

Comment: Btw, this is a theorem from Linear Algebra Done Right by Axler, isn't it?

Comment: @CrabMan no idea, i just have this question in my textbook

Answer (score 1):

If $V$ is $n$-dimensional, then $\mathcal{L}(V)$ is $n^2$-dimensional. Therefore, every list of $n^2+1$ linear operators on $V$ will be linearly dependent. In particular, $I, T, T^2, \dots, T^{n^2}$ is linearly dependent. Therefore there exists a nontrivial linear combination of these linear operators that sums to zero.

Comment: so to clarify, the combination is linearly dependent because $L$ maps from $V$ to $V$? Can you explain this a bit more, I kinda get it, but I don't fully understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: @charles Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$, $W$ is an $m$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Then $\mathcal{L}(V, W)$ is an $nm$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a field, $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{F}$. Suppose $v_1 \in V, \dots, v_{n+1} \in V$ is any list of vectors in $V$ of length $n+1$. Then it's linearly dependent.

Comment: So I need $k>n^2$, and it will be linearly dependent? How can I put together a proof of this? Also is this set the basis {$ I,T,T^2,…,T^n$} for $L$?

Comment: Yes, for any $k > n^2$ any list of $k$ linear operators will be linearly dependent.

Comment: $\{I, T, T^2, \dots, T^n\}$ is not necessarily a basis. For example, perhaps $T$ is the zero operator.

Comment: Thanks for the help so far, I'm just so confused. I feel like I'm close to getting it, but my explanations so far seem weak. Can you explain me a bit more on why  $ k>n^2$ will make it linearly dependent. I'm trying to justify me logic, but I think I need some more

Comment: @charles Try proving the two theorems I gave in my first and second comments. That'll give you that $k > n^2$ will make it linearly dependent.

Comment: I proved this one!! :  Suppose $F$ is a field, $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$, $W$ is an $m$-dimensional vector space over $F$. Then $L(V,W)$ is an $nm$-dimensional vector space over $F$. 
I'm having a tough time with the second one though for :  F is a field, V is an n-dimensional vector space over F. Suppose v1∈V,…,vn+1∈V is any list of vectors in V of length n+1. Then it's linearly dependent.